# BackboneJS Set all model attributes except one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to do the following;

```
self.myModel.set("myCollAttr", response.get('myCollAttr'));
```

So I want to set all the attributes that are there in response.get('myCollAttr') , except for one (say "skipThisAttr").

How can I handle the same using BackboneJS?

I know I can individually set all the other attributes (except the one I want to be NOT set)...But there are around 15-20 attributes. So I want to do it the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

`self.myModel.set("myCollAttr", _.omit(response.get('myCollAttr'), 'skipThisAttr'));`